# Condense 3 SELECTS down to one table

Tags: mysql

The three statement (a little contrived for simplicity) are:

```
SELECT `user_id` WHERE `movie_id` = 1
SELECT `user_id` WHERE `movie_id` = 2
SELECT `user_id` WHERE `movie_id` = 3
```

What I would like to do is twofold:

1. Join the three of the above into a single table of ID's that match all three of the movie_id
2. Make all of this one query to reduce MySQL reads to speed up performance

I am sure there is a simple way to do it, but I am not the strongest SQL user, so thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select count(distinct movie_ID), user_ID 
from table where move_Id in (1,2,3)
group by user_ID
Having count(distinct Movie_ID) = 3
```

What this does is obtain a distinct count of movies per user_ID. it then limits the results to only those users having a count of 3.

Comment: My understanding is that IN replaces multiple OR's, in my case they need to have all the movies

Comment: Sorry that was unclear in the original request.  I've modified the query to count distinct occurrences of movie ID per user.  You wouldn't need the district if you can guarantee a user will only have 0 or 1 associations to a movie_ID and only 0 and 1

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to me seems:

```
SELECT user_id FROM table_name WHERE movie_id IN (1,2,3);
```

Alternatively you could use the UNION method suggested by xQbert, but I would run an EXPLAIN query to see what SQL statement provided the most efficient result.

Comment: Could you explain the EXPLAIN query?

Comment: Take a look at the MYSQL Reference manual on EXPLAIN: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html